# How to avoid self via header append in invite request message in kamailio?

Tags: kamailio

I need to avoid self via update by kamailio on every invite request packet.
I used t-relay function to send out the invite packet to next hop.
In t-relay functionality, they added via self append.
Purpose to avoid self via in invite request packet basically do not want to get notify on call events like ringing, 200 etc.
Please help me on this.

Checked with kamailio parameters changes to achieve this , but there is no such a configuration through mod params in kamailio.

Comment: If you need help, you must find a way to clarify it. Maybe add some examples of packets. It is impossible to understand your goal.